# Android application how to check if i am not using too much Battery

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler, battery, batterymanager

How can i check if my apk that i created is don't use too much of the battery and not arm the usage of the battery itself.
Is there any tests or code to do or add for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power).
it covers all the different parts of the battery optimization process.

In order to monitor battery stats of the phone I'll suggest you [Battery Historian](https://github.com/google/battery-historian) by Google.